# div id for angular ui-grid cell selected

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying out angular ui-grid (http://ui-grid.info) and i cant figure out how to specify a div ID for a selected cell ? When I click on a cell it highlights but I would like some jquery events on click (popup...info...text...etc)

This is the orig cell selection:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding">Username</div>
```

I'm wondering if possible to get something like:

```
<div id="username-1234" tabindex="-1" class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding">Username</div>
```

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.pinning']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {

    $scope.gridOptions = { };

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        { field:'fullname', width:150, pinnedLeft: true, displayName: 'Name' },
        { field:'Day01', width:50, displayName: '01' },
        { field:'Day02', width:50, displayName: '02' },
        { field:'Day03', width:50, displayName: '03' },
        { field:'Day04', width:50, displayName: '04' },
        { field:'Day05', width:50, displayName: '05' }
];
```

Example image of my grid:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **cellTemplate**

Is possible to get something like:

```
<div id="username-1234" tabindex="-1" class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding">Username</div>
```

I don't know what is "1234", so use field name like this:

```
<div id="username-fieldname" tabindex="-1" class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding">Username</div>
```

This is the cell template

```
'<div id={{row.entity.name}}-{{col.colDef.name}} class="ui-grid-cell-contents"> {{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>'
```

[Here is Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cPCFehMIAYUNM4MlCcw4?p=preview)

P.s *name* of {{row.entity.name}} is field name, in your case is fullname, example like this:

```
'<div id={{row.entity.fullname}}-{{col.colDef.name}} class="ui-grid-cell-contents"> {{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>'
```